# JavaScript Changing dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

This is my JS code. I'm adding an `ul` to my `div#columns`.
Now I'd like to add some stuff to each of my new `li` elements but nothing happens. Same code works for elements which aren't dynamic.
How can I use my code for my new `li` elements?
I know that the problem is that my script can't see my new elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a.tableName').on('click', function () {
    $.getJSON("/ClientDatabaseManagement/ListColumns", { TableName: $(this).text() }, function (data) {
        var items = [];
        var i = 0; // ilość kolumn
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            items.push("<li id='" + key + "' class='" + "list-group-item" + "'>" + val + "</li>");
        });
        $("<ul/>", {
            "class": "list-group checked-list-box",
            html: items.join("")
        }).appendTo("div#columns").hide().animate({ height: 'toggle' }, 1000);
    });   
})
```

This is the part that doesn't work

```
$('.list-group.checked-list-box .list-group-item').each(function () {
        var $widget = $(this),
            $checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox" class="hidden" />'),
            color = ($widget.data('color') ? $widget.data('color') : "primary"),
            style = ($widget.data('style') == "button" ? "btn-" : "list-group-item-"),
            settings = {
                on: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check'
                },
                off: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked'
                }
            };
        $widget.css('cursor', 'pointer')
        $widget.append($checkbox);
        $widget.on('click', function () {
            $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
            $checkbox.triggerHandler('change');
            updateDisplay();
        });
        $checkbox.on('change', function () {
            updateDisplay();
        }); 
    });    
})  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following :

```
$widget.on('click', function () {
        var checkbox =  $(this).find("input:checkbox");
        checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.is(':checked'));
        checkbox.triggerHandler('change');
        updateDisplay();
    });
```

Comment: A code-only answer will never be as good as an answer with, if not some accompanying text to explain, comments. — [During review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10297554).

Comment: But first I have to take the widget from somewhere
the problem is here already:

       $('.list-group.checked-list-box .list-group-item').each(function () {
        var $widget = $(this)

Script just can`t see my new 'li' elements

Comment: Your second part must be inside the $(document).ready function, otherwise the second part will be executed and your <li> still not created and not found on your page

Comment: I added all your code inside the ready function and it works : https://jsfiddle.net/shhade/dtzoxgoa/